Windows 11 inaccessible boot device. Diskpart list disk - no ssd found
Preconditions:
Dual boot - Windows 11 Pro and Ubuntu 20.04.
Few days ago, when trying to load my windows as usual - get BSOD - inaccessible boot device.
Load from bootable flash drive.
Try to repair via command prompt.
bootrec /fixmbr - the operation completed successful.
bootrec /fixboot - and get error - access is denied.
diskpart list disk and list volume - shows only my flash drive (
Any suggestions???












Your problem is the host operating system or with the guest operating system on the VM?

host operating system. Cannot load Windows 11. Get inaccessible boot device error (blue screen)

So, what is the relevance of VMWare?

No relevance. I'll remove it from the description.

You should check UEFI just to confirm but very likely the drive is gone.

No. A can access to this disk from Ubuntu. Everything is fine, data is not corrupted!

@Joep van Steen - add to the questions description. It is my NVME drive, that have windows 11 . Ubuntu was installed on another physical SSD drive

@Joep van Steen - i found some guide - https://gist.github.com/vgmoose/4e74aca92787e79661defc16960a10f3
In section Bonus 2 - the author sad "If you mess around with those commands, but still nothing seems to fix it, I would suggest just completely deleting the EFI partition".
At the moment i don't know how to do it. at the same time, i need to keep ubuntu working - since i work on it.

The Windows machine. Legacy Mode is enabled or disabled? Specifically, and your screenshots from Linux don’t indicate this, is the disk MBR or GPT? Show us what partitions are on the disk. It’s weird that Windows does not even detect it. You would delete the EFI from within Linux, but that would make the disk unable to boot, but that’s already the case just makes it harder to solve your current problem. Dont follow that advice… the suggestion is silly.

@Ramhound
According to screen disk is on GPT.

@WebMaster - You just added the screenshot. It wasn’t there before I asked. You don’t get this error without a disk failure.

@Ramhound i can't find a Legacy Mode inside my EFI. A add some more screens with my EFI

@Ramhound
Are you saying that my NVME disk is damaged? I'm trying to understand - is this a software problem or a physical device problem?

You either modified the EFI partition or you lost data on the EFI partition. The EFI partition is where the necessary boot loader for Windows is located. You made no mention of modifying the EFI partition.

@Ramhound
Manually, I did not make changes to EFI.
I booted the operating system as usual. I found that there was no sound (some old driver problem) and rebooted the laptop. Usually this solved the sound problem. But when I rebooted this time - I got a blue screen.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Ramhound add some screens from gparted
